# How to prevent NumLock from disabling?

Tags: java, keyboard, capslock, num-lock, numpad

I'm making a simple game and I want to control it using numeric keyboard (including NumLock key). A player should be able to press several keys simultaneously, or press and hold any key.

After NumLock key is pressed, I have to turn NumLock back on through `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK, Boolean.TRUE)` so that `VK_NUMPADx` keys won't stop responding to presses.

The problem with such an approach is that `setLockingKeyState` seems to emulate `VK_NUM_LOCK` press. So `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` are called twice once for user input and once to turn NumLock on (if needed). When you press and hold NumLock it switches on and off constantly.

How can I avoid such a behaviour and get NumLock to work like any other key?

Comment: If your game can only be controlled using the numeric keypad, a lot of laptop users will not be able to play it.

Comment: It uses the whole keyboard, including numeric keypad if available. It's not even half way done yet though.

Comment: Why not have both KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT and KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4 invoke the same action?  Then the state of NumLock doesn't matter.  Obviously the same applies for VK_KP_RIGHT and VK_NUMPAD6, etc.

Comment: Good idea. But for some reason on my notebook when NumLock is off `VK_NUMPAD4` (and other keys) becomes `VK_LEFT` and not `VK_KP_LEFT`. I'd like to keep arrows for other options.

Comment: It would seem your notebook (and probably many others) doesn't have a fully functional numeric keypad, then.  Which goes back to my first comment: a numeric keypad isn't reliably available.